# MongoDb "AnyIn" filter method in C# gives compiler error

Tags: c#, mongodb

The following method tries to find documents in a Mongo collection with several filters using '&' operator:

```
public MyEntity GetByUserRefsGuidDate(List<OrgReference> userRefs, string guid, DateTime date)
        {
            var userGuids = new List<String>();
            foreach (var userRef in userRefs)
                userGuids.Add(userRef.Guid);
            var filterBuilder = Builders<MyEntity>.Filter;
            var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(e => e.IsAnswered, true) &
                         filterBuilder.AnyIn(e => e.UserRef.Guid, userGuids) &
                         filterBuilder.Eq(e => e.Guid, guid) &
                         filterBuilder.Eq(e => e.Date, date);

        }
```

The `AnyIn` filter method gives me the following error:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'FilterDefinition<MyEntity>' 
because it is not a delegate type.
```

Guids are just string values.
MyEntity class:

```
public class MyEntity
    {

        [BsonId]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public ObjectId MongoId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Guid { get; set; }

        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public OrgReference UserRef { get; set; }

        public bool IsAnswered { get; set; }

        [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    }
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AnyIn` method in MongoDB driver has following signature (considering Expressions version):

```
public FilterDefinition<TDocument> AnyIn<TItem>(Expression<Func<TDocument, IEnumerable<TItem>>> field, IEnumerable<TItem> values);
```

which means that it can be used to match nested array from the database document against your in memory collection.

Based on provided `SurveyEntity` class it seems like `UserRef.Guid` is a single value not a collection (array) so you should use `In` which has following signature:

```
public FilterDefinition<TDocument> In<TField>(Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> field, IEnumerable<TField> values);
```

So it matches single value from your database document against in-memory collection. Try:

```
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(e => e.IsAnswered, true) &
            filterBuilder.In(e => e.UserRef.Guid, userGuids) &
            filterBuilder.Eq(e => e.Guid, guid) &
            filterBuilder.Eq(e => e.Date, date);
```

It might be confusing because both `AnyIn` and `In` will get translated to `$in` in MongoDB query language but since C# is a strongly typed language they had to introduce separate method for collections.